# Making several similar specific methods generic

Tags: c#

I have a method like so...

```
    static async Task GetLeads(ForceClient client)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Get Leads");
        var accts = new List<Lead>();
        var results = await client.QueryAsync<Lead>(Lead._select);
        var totalSize = results.TotalSize;
        Console.WriteLine("Queried " + totalSize + " leads.");
        accts.AddRange(results.Records);
        Console.WriteLine("Added " + results.Records.Count + " leads...");
        var nextRecordsUrl = results.NextRecordsUrl;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextRecordsUrl))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found more records...");

            while (true)
            {
                var continuationResults = await client.QueryContinuationAsync<Lead>(nextRecordsUrl);
                Console.WriteLine("Queried an additional " + continuationResults.Records.Count + " leads.");
                accts.AddRange(continuationResults.Records);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(continuationResults.NextRecordsUrl)) break;

                nextRecordsUrl = continuationResults.NextRecordsUrl;
            }
        }
        Upsert(accts, Lead.target);
    }
```

I have another method like so..

```
    static async Task GetSupplierProducts(ForceClient client)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Get SupplierProduct");
        var accts = new List<SupplierProduct>();
        var results = await client.QueryAsync<SupplierProduct>(SupplierProduct._select);
        var totalSize = results.TotalSize;
        Console.WriteLine("Queried " + totalSize + " SupplierProduct.");
        accts.AddRange(results.Records);
        Console.WriteLine("Added " + results.Records.Count + " SupplierProduct...");
        var nextRecordsUrl = results.NextRecordsUrl;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextRecordsUrl))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found more records...");

            while (true)
            {
                var continuationResults = await client.QueryContinuationAsync<SupplierProduct>(nextRecordsUrl);
                Console.WriteLine("Queried an additional " + continuationResults.Records.Count + " SupplierProduct.");
                accts.AddRange(continuationResults.Records);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(continuationResults.NextRecordsUrl)) break;

                nextRecordsUrl = continuationResults.NextRecordsUrl;
            }
        }
        Upsert(accts, SupplierProduct.target);
    }
```

How can I make a method that abstracts this behavior generically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The types `Lead` and `SupplierProduct` must somehow be related in the sense that they either implement the same interface or inherit from the same base class to make this work. Apparently the similarities are `_select` which apparently is a static member which cannot be included in an interface. Furthermore, the generation of human-readable strings would have to be refactored into the types.

If `Base` would be hypothetical base class, the signature of the generic function would have to be as follows.

```
static async Task Get<T>(ForceClient client) where T : Base
```

Comment: Yes Lead and Supplier product descend from a common interface IUpsertable

Comment: Are you saying I should use a concrete base class for this rather than an interface?

Comment: No, but an interface does not permit a declaration of static members.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both Lead and SupplierProduct inherits the same Parent:

```
 static async Task GetMyInstance<T>(ForceClient client) where T : Parent
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Get " + T.GetType().Name);
        var accts = new List<T>();
        var results = await client.QueryAsync<T>(T._select);
        var totalSize = results.TotalSize;
        Console.WriteLine("Queried " + totalSize + " " + T.GetType().Name +".");
        accts.AddRange(results.Records);
        Console.WriteLine("Added " + results.Records.Count + T.GetType().Name + "...");
        var nextRecordsUrl = results.NextRecordsUrl;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextRecordsUrl))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found more records...");

            while (true)
            {
                var continuationResults = await client.QueryContinuationAsync<T>(nextRecordsUrl);
                Console.WriteLine("Queried an additional " + continuationResults.Records.Count + " " + T.GetType().Name + ".");
                accts.AddRange(continuationResults.Records);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(continuationResults.NextRecordsUrl)) break;

                nextRecordsUrl = continuationResults.NextRecordsUrl;
            }
        }
        Upsert(accts, T.target);
    }
```

Please note that Parent should contain _select and target for this to work

And you call it like this:

```
var foo = GetMyInstance<Lead>(forceClient);
```

or

```
var foo = GetMyInstance<SupplierProduct>(forceClient);
```

Answer (score 1):

This likely won't suffice fully, but when I want to make multiple partial-similar methods accessible through a single function, I tend to pass target-strings and use a repeating switch-statement on them.
This way we can also run multiple actions after each other by supplying an array of targets.

Note; this code isn't debugged or anything, I just wanted to point you towards how switch-statements might be of some use to you. It wasn't possible for me to give a more comprehensive answer because I can't fully understand the intent of your code.

```
static async Task GetRecordsFor(ForceClient client, string[] targets )
    {
        foreach (string target in targets){
            switch ( target )
            {
                case 'leads':
                    Console.WriteLine("Get Leads");
                    var accts = new List<Lead>();
                    // more specific code for fetching leads
                    break;

                case 'suppliers':
                    Console.WriteLine("Get SupplierProduct");
                    var accts = new List<SupplierProduct>();
                    // more specific code for fetching suppliers
                    break;
            }
            // Actions you want to perform on each of these.
            accts.AddRange(continuationResults.Records);
        }
    }
```